# primeng 16: toolbar with customized icons

Tags: primeng, toolbar

I need a toolbar with customized icons in an angular 16 application with primeng 16.
I found the following sample code in primeng website:

```html
<p-toolbar>
    <div class="p-toolbar-group-start">
        <p-button label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="mr-2"></p-button>
        <p-button label="Upload" icon="pi pi-upload" styleClass="p-button-success"></p-button>
        <i class="p-toolbar-separator pi pi-bars mr-2" style="vertical-align: middle"></i>
        <p-splitButton label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" [model]="items" styleClass="p-button-warning"></p-splitButton>
    </div>
    <div class="p-toolbar-group-end">
        <p-button icon="pi pi-search" class="mr-2"></p-button>
        <p-button icon="pi pi-calendar" styleClass="p-button-success mr-2"></p-button>
        <p-button icon="pi pi-times" styleClass="p-button-danger"></p-button>
    </div>
</p-toolbar>
```

In this sample, the icons are from primeng. How can I use my icons ?

Thank you,
Zvika